# Including JS libraries in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem with adding .js libraries to functions.php file. Here's the full code of the file:

```
<?php
function child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('nudie'), '1.0' );
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_styles');
function wp_adding_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'easing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'easing' );

    wp_register_script( 'scrolling-nav', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scrolling-nav.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolling-nav' );

    wp_register_script( 'scrollreveal', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scrollreveal.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollreveal' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_adding_scripts', 20 );
```

All paths are right and libraries are being loaded before closing `</body>` tag as they should, but not one of them works. I've set a priority of 20 for them so they are being loaded after everything else, but that didn't help me as well.

Comment: So what errors are thrown? *"not a one of them works"* is not much of a problem description to work from considering we don't know what they should do. If they are all being loaded what is the relevance of showing us how they are enqueued?

Comment: There is simply no error, they load but don't work, though I've added all the necessary classes, so I was wondering if I included them correctly and what else I may do to fix this problem.

Comment: What about the script with your code that activates the plugins?

Comment: In addition to what @charlietfl is inquiring, I noticed that the style path appears to be incomplete? also, you gave it a handle of 'child-theme-style' (singular) and then you're attempting to enqueue 'child-theme-styles' (plural).

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I've solved the problem, it was in jQuery which wasn't loading properly for some reason. I've changed one of included JS libraries a little and everything works fine now.